# create json with multi key javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to create a json like this:

```
{
    "19/01/2018": ["10", "11", "12", "18"],
    "20/01/2018": ["13", "14", "15"],
    "21/01/2018": ["10", "14", "16", "17"],
    "24/01/2018": ["10", "15", "17"],
    "26/01/2018": ["10", "10", "13" ,"18"],
    "20/02/2018": ["10", "10", "13" ,"18"]
}
```

Currently, I have an event and each click it launch this function. But, never create a new line, it ecrase the same line. I don't know how to do it...

```
    this.createJSON = (date, heure) => {
        let json = {};

        if (localStorage.getItem('test')) {
            console.log('YEnA');
            json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test'));
        } else {
            console.log('Empty');
            json = {
                date : '',
                hour: []
            };
        }

        if ($.inArray(heure, json.hour) === -1) {
            console.log('Jsuis pas encore lo');

            json.date = date;
            json.date[date] += json.hour.push(heure);
        }



        localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(json));


};
```

Need help.

Thanks

Comment: localStorage is by name. Since you always overwrite the name 'test', there will only be one item in storage with that name. Try appending an id or something to the name so you can differentiate between multiple lines. But the main question should be, why would you want to update the localStorage on every click anyway?

Comment: @Shilly I don't found a better idea. When I click, i would like to insert the values in array, but at each click my json is reset, never save...

Comment: `setItem` will overwrite the current value, so you have to make sure it's complete. AS the other guy posted, `json.date[date] += json.hour.push(heure);` doesn't actually push anything. You propably just want `json.hour.push(heure);` to push to the array. As you have written it, you create a new property on the `date` property and then try to concat the result of the push to it instead of pushing to the `hour` array. My point however is, you could bind the localStorage to the onload and onunload event of the entire page instead of updating every click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your first JSON I think this should work:

```
this.createJSON = (date, heure) => {
    let json = {};

    if (localStorage.getItem('test')) {
        console.log('YEnA');
        json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test'));
    }

    if ($.inArray(heure, json.hour) === -1) {
        console.log('Jsuis pas encore lo');

        if (json[date] === undefined) {
            json[date] = [ heure ];
        } else {
            json[date].push(heure);
        }
    }

    localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(json));
};
```

Comment: Oh god, thanks... During my test, I forgot the [] to [heure] ... Thanks dude